# Count the amount of a specific row elements combinations in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to find how many times a certain combination of row elements occur in an array. I tried to use the numpy.where command, but I can not get it to work. As an example:

```
   array([['a', '2', 'b'],
          ['c', '4', 'a'],
          ['b', '2', 'c'],
          ['a', '5', 'b'],
          ['b', '7', 'a'],
          ['a', '3', 'b']], 
  dtype='|S1')
```

I want to now how many time the combination of 'a' in the first row and 'b' in the third row occurs (note that the combination of 'a' and 'b' is different from the combination 'b' and  'a'). Do not mind the numbers in the second column, those are additional information I use later in my code.
The result from the operation should be 3, in the example given above. I am trying to look for a fast way because this definition will be used many times in my code (so a combination of multiple for loops will simply take too long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided your matrix is contained in variable `arr`, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

arr = arr.astype('U')

arr[np.logical_and(arr[:,0]=='a', arr[:,2]=='b')]
#array([['a', '2', 'b'],
#       ['a', '5', 'b'],
#       ['a', '3', 'b']],
#      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for.